# Get the name of a class as a string in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to take a class name and convert it to a string in C#?

As part of the Entity Framework, the .Include method takes in a dot-delimited list of strings to join on when performing a query. I have the class model of what I want to join, and for reasons of refactoring and future code maintenance, I want to be able to have compile-time safety when referencing this class.

Thus, is there a way that I could do this:

```
class Foo
{
}

tblBar.Include ( Foo.GetType().ToString() );
```

I don't think I can do GetType() without an instance. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Include requires a property name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx), not a class name. Hence, it's the name of the property you want, not the name of its type.  [You can get that with reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Craig, I've found this that also helped: http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entityframework-include-with-func.aspx

Answer (score 109):

You can't use `.GetType()` without an instance because `GetType` is a method.

You can get the name from the type though like this:

```
typeof(Foo).Name
```

And as pointed out by Chris, if you need the assembly qualified name you can use

```
typeof(Foo).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also do something like this:

```
Type CLASS = typeof(MyClass);
```

And then you can just access the name, namespace, etc.

```
 string CLASS_NAME = CLASS.Name;
 string NAMESPACE = CLASS.Namespace;
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to using `typeof(Foo).ToString()`, you could use [nameof()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof):

```
nameof(Foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
typeof(Foo).ToString()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `DbSet<contact>` instead of `ObjectSet<contact>`, so you can use lambda as a parameter, eg `tblBar.Include(a => a.foo)`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using reflection, is to use the MethodBase class.

In your example, you could add a static property (or method) that provides you with the info you want. Something like:

```
class Foo
{
    public static string ClassName
    {
        get
        {
            return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to use it without generating an instance of the type:

```
tblBar.Include(Foo.ClassName);
```

Which at runtime will give you:

```
tblBar.Include("Foo");
```