# Retrieve class name hierarchy as string

Tags: c#

Our system complexity has risen to the point that we need to make permission names tied to the client from the database more specific. In the client, permissions are referenced from a static class since a lot of client functionality is dependent on the permissions each user has and the roles have a ton of variety. I've referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179700/get-the-name-of-a-class-as-a-string-in-c) as an example, but I'm looking for a more specific use case. Take for instance this reference, where PermissionAlpha would be a const string:

```
return HasPermission(PermissionNames.PermissionAlpha);
```

Which is great, except now that things are growing more complex the classes are being structured like this:

```
public static class PermissionNames
{
    public static class PermissionAlpha
    {
        public const string SubPermission = "PermissionAlpha.SubPermission";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find an easy way to reference PermissionAlpha in this new setup that will act similar to the first declaration above. Would the only way to do this be to resort to pulling the value of the class name like in the example below? I'm trying to keep all the names in one place that can be reference anywhere in the application.

```
public static class PermissionAlpha
{
    public static string Name { get { return typeof(PermissionAlpha).Name; } }
}
```

** Edit ** - Added missing permission name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would be too big of a change for you with the size of your project, but we have all of our business objects split into partial classes. One is for manual changes and one gets generated. During code-generation, we write the permission keys into the generated side of the partial classes from our "single source of truth". We're using a set of classes as our source of truth and CodeDom to generate, but you could also use a database as your source and use T4, CodeSmith, or others to generate.

Comment: I think for this particular change, that would be a bit difficult given the time constraints. However, we're hoping to port to Silverlight sometime soon and this would definitely be something to consider. Are there any examples of how this would be set up? It's a bit hard to conceptualize.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this after doing some more research. Switching to this model looks like it might be a good method moving forward. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Once you start code-generation you'll never want to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create reflectable attribute(s) on the classes in question? That way one can add all the extra information required. I provide a way of divining attributes on my blog article entitled:

[C# Using Extended Attribute Information on Objects](http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=28)

HTH

Comment: I've considered it and we do actually do this for other examples in code, specifically Enums, I'd rather just reference the class names to avoid using so many ValueConverters in XAML and referencing and using GetDescriptionAttibute() in each place I need to reference permissions (which is much more common than the Enums).