# Dictionary to Stack Class Types Together

Tags: c#, dictionary, stack, unity-game-engine

Enemy classes involved:

```
public abstract Enemy : MonoBehaviour {}

public class A : Enemy {}

public class B : Enemy {}
```

I have a dictionary. I want make the dictionary **contain a stack for every type of Enemy.**

```
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
       // prefabs
       public GameObject a, b;

       public Dictionary<Enemy, Stack> eDictionary; 

       void Start()
       {
          eDictionary = new Dictionary<Enemy, Stack>(); 
          Fill(a, 10);
          Fill(b, 10);
       }
    }
```

How I make the stack and keys.

```
public void Fill(Enemy e, int howMany)
{
   Stack s = new Stack();
   for(int I = 0; I < howMany; I++)
   {
      GameObject g = MonoBehavior.Instantiate(e.gameObject) as GameObject;
      s.Push(g);
   }

  eDictionary.Add(e, s)
}
```

The main problem is: **How do I make the keys in such a way that the Enemies of type A stack together with 1 key?**

When I go into the `generalized` enemy classes A and B and try to add that enemy to the corresponding stack due to its key, I get key not matching error. I do this when I pop the Enemies out of the stack then when I am done with them I want to push them into the dictionary's stack (it fails at that point).

Comment: Why not use `Stack<Enemy>`?

Comment: I will have different enemies. So I want a stack for every kind of enemy. Unless you mean give a type to the Stack inside the dictionary, in that case it is not needed.

Comment: @MikeJohn Seems like you're confusing the type `Enemy` with *instances* of `Enemy`. Try to use a string or Enum (e.g. `enum EnemyType`) instead for the keys. Or maybe it's possble to use `typeof(Enenemy)` as key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue might be to do with the key you're using.

When you're adding the stack to the Dictionary, you're giving it a key of an instance of enemy.  So even if you reference that dictionary with the same type later on, it will be a different instance so it won't match.

One solution is to use the name of the class, as the key, rather than the object itself.

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/179711/1514883

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question but I will accept it and ask my question differently now that I know the problem.