# Dictionary that takes a type and a stack

Tags: c#, dictionary, types, unity-game-engine

I want to make a Dictionary that has a type of a class and a stack. The type of a class will be the key for the dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<typeof(Enemy), Stack> d;
```

The line above, of course, won't compile.

---

Enemy classes involved:

```
public abstract Enemy : MonoBehaviour {}

public class A : Enemy {}

public class B : Enemy {}
```

I am building up on my previous question: [Dictionary to Stack Class Types Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110376/dictionary-to-stack-class-types-together)
(no need to read it unless you really want to).

**So how do I use my class type as the key in the dictionary?** 
I rather not use String names or enums.

Dictionary should look like this in memory:

```
[A] --> stack[]
[B] --> stack[]
```

That is, every Enemy type gets a stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type,Stack>();
```

Usage would be:

```
dictionary.Add(typeof(A),new Stack());
dictionary.Add(typeof(B),new Stack());

dictionary[typeof(A)].Push(new Object());
var objectFromStackOfA = dictionary[typeof(A)].Pop();
```

Comment: Writing `Type` doesn't compile. I get this : "The type or namespace name 'Type' could not be found"

Comment: @Mike John, add `using System;`

Comment: That helped. It works perfectly. Include in your answer the push and pop. They look something like this `[enemy.GetType()]` and I'll definitely accept your answer (that way other people can learn later on).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to define some dictionary

```
<K,V>
```

where K is any object of a class which is a subclass of Enemy?
Or ... where K is any Type which subclasses Enemy?

I've thought on this myself on a few occasions.

So... I am not quite familiar with the 
newest C# language features.
I would probably just define it as

```
<Type, V>
```

then as things are added to this structure make a check myself if 
the type tp added actually IsSubclassOf the Enemy type, and if not
I would throw an exception.

But there might be a better way using
the newest C# language features.

Comment: Where the key is the type of the subclass of Enemy.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use string as a type of your class:
override the ToString() method of your classes, then use it to add in the dictionary!

```
public class Enemy { }
public class A : Enemy
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return "A";
    }
}
public class B : Enemy
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "B";
    }
}
public class Stack { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Stack> d = new Dictionary<string, Stack>();
        A obj1 = new A();
        A obj2 = new A();
        B obj3 = new B();
        B obj4 = new B();
        d.Add(obj1.ToString(), new Stack());
        d.Add(obj2.ToString(), new Stack());
        d.Add(obj3.ToString(), new Stack());
        d.Add(obj4.ToString(), new Stack());
    }
}
```

Comment: You say simple to use String. Is there any advantage to using String over the Type? Perhaps it is faster?

Comment: I don't know! I prefer this because it's intuitive for a dictionary to have a string key.

Comment: My guess would be that you pay the price for creating that string every time you want to push or pop. That might be a separate question worth asking here in StackOverflow.